# How can I capture certain hashtag in Twitter in C#?

Tags: c#, twitter

I have a silver light App that captures the tweets of certain Twitter user. I want to modify that App so that It captures any tweet in the public timeline with a certain #hashtag. How can I do that ? or is there any ready code for that ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [Twitter Search API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3A-search).

For example, let's say you want to search for #ipad. Then just use:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=%23ipad
```

And you'll get results containing the #ipad tag.

For the C# part, you can use [Tweetsharp](http://tweetsharp.com/) C# library, or just use DOT NET's http client to perform your query.